# AngularJS - Write in dynamic Scope Variables

Tags: angularjs, websocket, scope

I am using AngularJS and the websocket tool https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-websocket to connect to my websocket Server.

No I am trying to write on dynamic Scope Variables, but it doesn't work.

```
        var webfront = ons.bootstrap('webfront', ['onsen', 'ngWebSocket']);

        webfront.factory('MyData', function($websocket) {
        var dataStream = $websocket('ws://{$smarty.const.IPADRESSE}:8000');
        console.log('Warte auf Antwort - Status '+dataStream.readyState);
            var data = {};

            dataStream.onMessage(function(message) {
                try {
                    var obj = JSON.parse(message.data); 
                    data.cStatus = obj.cStatus;
                    data.kLeseAdresse = obj.kLeseAdresse;
                    console.log(data);
                } catch(e) {
                data.cStatus= '';
                }
            });

            dataStream.onOpen(function(msg) {
                console.log("Verbunden - Status "+dataStream.readyState);
            });

            dataStream.onError(function(event) {
                console.log('connection Error', event);
            });

            return data;
        });

        webfront.controller('chater', function ($scope, MyData) {

            $scope['ng12289'] = MyData;

        });
```

This is my Code. $scope['ng12289'] is working perfect, but if I change ng12289 with dynamic Variable, nothing happens.

Valuename is in MyData.kLeseAdresse

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Does $scope.my_dynamic_variable work?